# What causes 'Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays'?

Tags: angular

I don't know what is the problem with my code

> Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList, AngularFireObject } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Employee } from '../Employee';

@Injectable()
export class EmployeeService {

  employees: AngularFireList<any[]>;
  Employee: AngularFireObject<any>;

  constructor( 
    public af: AngularFireDatabase
  ) { 
    this.employees = this.af.list('/employees/employees') as AngularFireList <Employee[]>;
  }
getEmployees(): AngularFireList <any[]> {
  return this.employees ; 
}
}
```

and this is my component

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { EmployeeService } from '../../services/employee.service';
import { Employee } from '../../Employee';
import { all } from 'q';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-employees',
  templateUrl: './employees.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employees.component.css']
})
export class EmployeesComponent implements OnInit {

  employees : Employee [];
  constructor(public employeeService : EmployeeService ) {

   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.employeeService.getEmployees().valueChanges().subscribe( employees => {
      this.employees = employees[0];
      console.log(this.employees);
    })
  }

}
```

This is the html file

```html
<table class="table table-dark">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      
      <th scope="col">First Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Email </th>
      <th scope="col">Country</th>
      <th scope="col">City</th>
      <th scope="col">Phone</th>
      <th scope="col">ID</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody >
    <tr *ngFor="let item of employees">
      <th >{{item.firstName}}</th>
      <th >{{item.lasttName}}</th>


    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: In your template, you are using `*ngIf` to try and loop through a collection, but the collection is actually just an object. You are setting `this.employees = employees[0];`, which would equate to setting `this.employees` the first object in an array. Perhaps this should really be `this.employees = employees;`.

Comment: Its Work thanks but there is another probleme with this
"Can not assign type' any [] [] 'to type' Employee []"

Comment: See if changing `employees: AngularFireList<any[]>;` to this `employees: AngularFireList<any>;` in your service fixes that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting *this.employees = employees[0];* and trying to loop through employees. But i suppose ***employees[0] is not an array or a iterable type***. 
If your intention is to make employees contain only the first element. try  this

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.employeeService.getEmployees().valueChanges().subscribe( employees => {
   this.employees = [employees[0]];
   console.log(this.employees);
 })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me guys

Comment: @MohamedAliLassoued If the answer is correct ,please mark your question as answered!